# finding how many times a sequence repeats in a data frame using python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas, math, scipy

Is there a way to find how many times a sequence repeats in a dataframe?

Lets say I have a dataframe with a large number of 1 and 3's and I wanted to see how much this sequence [3,1,3,3,1] repeats.

here's an example list. 3,1,3,3,1,3,3,1,3,3,1,3,1,1,1,1,3,1,3,1,1,3,3,3

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do

this first part would be true **3,1,3,3,1**,3,3,1,3,3,1,3,1,1,1,1,3,1,3,1,1,3,3,3

this second part would be false 3,1,3,3,1,**3,3,1,3,3**,1,3,1,1,1,1,3,1,3,1,1,3,3,3

and the third part would be false
3,1,3,3,1,3,3,1,3,3,**1,3,1,1,1**,1,3,1,3,1,1,3,3,3

I want to analyze sections at a time according to the length of the sequence I'm trying to find. In numeric order of the data frame.

My data Is in a dateandtime format. But I can change that.

Thanks for all your help I really appreciate it everything everybody does on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This converts a list of numbers into a comma separated string, and then compares each sequential chunk to the target.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

my_list = [3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]
target = [3, 1, 3, 3, 1]
n = len(target)
>>> sum(all(a == b for a, b in izip_longest(target, my_list[(i * n):((i + 1) * n)])) 
        for i in range(len(my_list) // n))
1
```

Below is an alternative method that converts the integers to strings and then compares the strings.

```
target = ",".join(str(number) for number in target)
>>> target
'3,1,3,3,1'
>>> sum(",".join(str(number) for number in my_list[(i * n):(i * n + n)]) == target 
        for i in range(len(my_list) / n))
1
```

To give some more intuition on what is going on, the list is chunked five elements at a time and then those elements are joined as a string.  These strings are then compared to the target string which was similarly converted, and the number of matches are then summed.

```
>>> [",".join(str(number) for number in my_list[(i * n):(i * n + n)]) 
     for i in range(len(my_list) / n)]
['3,1,3,3,1', '3,3,1,3,3', '1,3,1,1,1', '1,3,1,3,1']
```

Comment: Is there a way that it doesn't use the same numbers in the sequence that it just checked. That's hard to explain. Like it checks the first five then checks the next five that arent in that sequence. Example will better explain it . checks these **3,1,3,3,1**,3,3,1,3,3,1,3,1,1,1,1,3,1,3,1,1,3,3,3   then checks these 3,1,3,3,1,**3,3,1,3,3**,1,3,1,1,1,1,3,1,3,1,1,3,3,3 and so on and so forth

Comment: That quick huh? Your a true master of your craft man. I've been thinking about this for awhile lol Thanks really appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = np.array([3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3])
target = np.array([3, 1, 3, 3, 1])
(my_list.reshape(-1, len(sequence)) == sequence[None, :]).all(axis=1)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

#### Step1

Convert list of integers into string.

#### Step2

Use **findall()** function of [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module to find all occurences of `target_string` in `my_list_string`.

```
import re
my_list = [3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3]
target = [3, 1, 3, 3, 1]

my_list_string = ''.join(str(e) for e in my_list)
target_string = ''.join(str(e) for e in target)

print(len(re.findall(target_string, my_list_string)))
```